# Cannot get element placed above others

Tags: css, slideshow

Here is the site

Whenever I hover over a link for the navigation, it appears behind the slideshow. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a

`z-index: 1;`

to

```
#slideshow ul {
    height: 320px;
    left: 10px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 620px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and a

`z-index: 1000;`

to

```
.menu li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

`z-index` specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with a greater stack order is placed in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty amazing. Thanks so much. Now, why 1000? Why not 2? or 3827?

Comment: You're welcome, @Matthew.  You could use 2 or 3827 if you like, as long as one is larger than the other.  I chose 1 and 1000 because they are so far apart there would likely be nothing in between that would interfere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the `z-index` (currently set to 200) of the `ul`, to be higher than the `z-index` of the slideshow (currently set to 1000).